# Finding the value of $\sum \limits ^{\infty}_{n=3,5,7,9....}\dfrac{2n \exp \left(-\pi n/2\right)}{\exp(\pi n)+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

From my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4403648/finding-the-value-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac22n1-exp-frac-pi2n1), I changed the sum into:

$\displaystyle \tag*{} \sum \limits ^{\infty}_{n=3,5,7,9....}\dfrac{2n \exp \left(-\pi n/2\right)}{\exp(\pi n)+1}$

Since my previous question, I still couldn't solve this. However, I think there is a solution using elliptical functions or Poisson's Summation formula. But I don't know them. I would still accept answers using them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you encounter this sum? If the numerator contained $2n^2$ instead of $2n$ then a closed form exists.

Comment: Indeed, not a particular value of modular form. With $\exp(\pi n)-1$ in the denominator or $2n (-1)^n$ instead of $2n$ there should be a closed-form as well. @ParamanandSingh

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I got this question from quora. And also can you answer for the $2n^2$ case? I like your answers a lot.

Comment: @4444: Would you share a link to the original question then?

Comment: @metamorphy https://qr.ae/pGLWdJ . It has been asked on both websites. I waited whether someone would answer on quora, no one did. So I asked on MSE.

Comment: You can put a separate question for $n^2$ case. Right now all I can do is refer you to this answer of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1798062/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I posted another question here with $n^2$ in numerator here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404818/finding-the-value-of-sum-limits-infty-n-3-5-7-9-dfrac2n2-exp-le